# How to allow this connection on the Firewall?

Tags: networking, server, firewall, iptables, nfs

I am trying to connect my Ubuntu Web Server to my Ubuntu Storage Server using NFS (Network File System).

But when I try to mount a Storage Server to the Web Server, I get a "Connection Timeout" message into the log.

I looked into the log (`/var/log/ufw.log`) which tells me this:

```
May 19 13:56:11 storage-server kernel:
[71803.508581] [UFW BLOCK]
IN=eth1
OUT= 
MAC=01:02:42:31:01:03:05:02:52:59:af:01:06:00 
SRC=2.2.2.2 
DST=1.1.1.1 
LEN=60 
TOS=0x00 
PREC=0x00 
TTL=64 
ID=64909 
DF 
PROTO=TCP 
SPT=818
DPT=2049 
WINDOW=29200 
RES=0x00 
SYN 
URGP=0
```

How can I allow this connection using `iptables` (Without opening for any other ports or for any other IPs)

I already tried running `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 2049 -s 2.2.2.2 -j ACCEPT`, `sudo iptables -L` and `sudo bash -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables.conf"` on my Storage Server.

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on both servers.

I have my storage server (IP `1.1.1.1`).
I have my web server (IP `2.2.2.2`).

NOTE: IPs are just examples and MAC address have been changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as the NFS port itself (port 2049), I think you will need to open the portmapper service port (111). I'm not smart enough to use iptables directly, so I would use ufw for this. You can restrict the allowed network range using CIDR addressing e.g.

```
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 111
```

If that still doesn't work, you may need to configure `nfs-kernel-server` to use a static `RPCMOUNTDOPTS` port as described in the Debian [SecuringNFS](https://wiki.debian.org/SecuringNFS) wiki. You can use `rpcinfo -p` to probe the current services / port settings.

Answer (score 1):

Try.

Change pleases of ip and port

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 2.2.2.2 -p tcp --dport 2049 -j ACCEPT
```